# Headline bug on edit profile

Tags: bug, status-completed

I discovered a small bug when I was editing my profile on stackoverflow (/users/edit/)

The title is:

```
FriendlyName(u.UserTypeId)
```

Seems very server side to me :)

Comment: This is the kind of situation where "me too" would be an appropriate comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fallout from some localization work on the edit page.

Was missing a server side code directive - this is fixed and will be with you in the next build (rev 2014.10.3.1908, meta rev 2014.10.3.2624).